# dynamic caching in meteor

Tags: caching, meteor, browser-cache

I've two different images of every user, think of it as a two images uploaded by the users.

I'm uploading those images to the s3 and I have the links

I want to cache those two different images for different users.

I saw the `meteor appcache` package looks like that is for static content only.

How to do that?

ANy ideas appreciated.